# How to get a Value's Key using index

Tags: lua

How does one get the key from a table value using the index, like this;

```
local myTable = {
Mary = 1000,
Bob = 2000,
Fred = 3000}

local keyAtIndex1 = myTable[1] ??? --- should return "Mary"
local keyAtIndexTwo = myTable[2] ??? --- should return "Bob"
```

Is there a pre-built method or property?

I am currently doing this;

```
function tableGetKeyFromValue(_table, _value)
  for k,v in pairs(_table) do
if v==_value then return k end
  end
 return nil
end
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: `tableGetKeyFromValue` doesn't do what your original code said. You wanted `myTable[2]` to return "Bob"; `tableGetKeyFromValue(myTable, 2)` would return `nil`, because there is no value of 2. Did you mean 2000?

Answer (score 2):

Keys in Lua tables do not have indices; they *are* indices. Keys in Lua tables are not ordered, so you cannot fetch them by some ordering.

Furthermore, there is no mechanism to fetch keys by their value. The map only goes one way: from keys to values. If you want to have a mapping from values to keys, you can build a separate table that stores that mapping easily enough.

However, nothing will exist to keep these two tables in sync with one another. That's fine if the table is more-or-less static.